# jquery nested ajax list and onclick function design

Tags: jquery, ajax, onclick, nested

I have a the following one to many datamodel:
Regions have Clients,
Clients have Notes and Alerts

And I have implemented the fetching an populating as follows:

```
When the page loads all the regions load and populate their view.
When you click on a region all the clients for that region load and populate their view.
When you click on a client all the notes/alerts for that client load and populate .their view.
```

The jquery code for this looks as follows:

```
    RegionDAO.getRegions(function(data){
        $("#regionlist").empty();
        $("#clientlist").empty();
        $(data).each(function(index){
            $("#regionlist").append("<li class='regionrow blendRow' id='"+this.rid+"'>" + this.name + "</li>");
        });
        $('.regionrow').blend(150);
        $(".regionrow").click(function(){
             $(".regionrow").removeClass("activerow");
             $("#"+$(this).attr("id")).addClass("activerow");
             RegionDAO.getClientsByRegion($(this).attr("id"),function(data){
                 $("#clientlist").empty();
                 $(data).each(function(index){
                     $("#clientlist").append("<li class='clientrow blendRow' id='"+this.cid+"'>" + this.lastname + "</li>");
                 });
                 $('.clientrow').blend(150);
                 $('.clientrow').click(function(){
                     RegionDAO.getNotesByClient($(this).attr("id"),function(data){
                         $("#notelist").empty();
                         $(data).each(function(index){
                             $("#notelist").append("<li class='noterow blendRow' id='"+this.nid+"'>" + this.text + "</li>");
                         });
                         $('.noterow').blend(150);                           
                     });
                    RegionDAO.getAlertsByClient($(this).attr("id"),function(data){
                         $("#alertlist").empty();
                         $(data).each(function(index){
                             $("#alertlist").append("<li class='alertrow blendRow' id='"+this.nid+"'>" + this.text + "</li>");
                         });
                         $('.alertrow').blend(150);                          
                     });
                 });
             });
        });
    });
});
```

Everything works really well until I implement the addRegion functionality in a seperate click handler. What I want to happen is that after you click save (I have a handler for it) the list of regions repopulate. The problem is that because it is in a seprate handler I have to redefine the entire nested list>click function structure again and thats code duplication. Here follows the addRegion Code:

```
$("#addregiondialog").dialog({                          
                    title: 'Add a region',
                    show: "up",
                    open: function(event, ui){

                    },
                    buttons: { "Save": function() {

                            $(this).dialog("close"); 

                            RegionDAO.addRegion($('#region_name').val());
                            RegionDAO.getRegions(function(data){
                                $("#regionlist").empty();
                                $("#clientlist").empty();
                                $(data).each(function(index){
                                    $("#regionlist").append("<li class='regionrow blendRow' id='"+this.rid+"'>" + this.name + "</li>");
                                });
                                $('.regionrow').blend(150);
                                $(".regionrow").click(function(){
                                    //MUST REDEFINE THE CLIENT LOADING AND CLICK STRUCTURE
                                    //HERE AS WELL AS THE CLICKS AND EVERYTHING FOR NOTES AND ALERTS. IE THE ABOVE CODE>
                                });

                            });
                        } 
                    }                       
                });
```

This seems like a very common pattern to me and was wondering what the best way was to implement this is because clearly (it works, but) this is not ideal.

Comment: I think you should consult the [jQuery on() doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/), look for delegated events.

Comment: I don't understand, please explain your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.click(), which is you use in the code above, is a shortcut of .bind('click').  This binds an event handler for all matching elements **already existing**.  There is .live(), a counterpart of .bind(), which does the same for elements that will be **added in the future** as well.  But the jQuery documentation states:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().
>
> This method provides a means to attach delegated event handlers to the
>   document element of a page, which simplifies the use of event handlers
>   when content is dynamically added to a page. See the discussion of
>   direct versus delegated events in the .on() method for more
>   information.

I meant this in my comment.
Now what you have to do (assuming `#parent` is a common parent of all `.regionrow`s) instead of

```
$(".regionrow").click(function(){
    (...)
});
```

is

```
$("#parent").on("click", ".regionrow", function(){
    (...)
});
```

Comment: For a moment there I thought you were smoking something but this certainly is a *very* powerful and useful feature. I have in the meantime gone and implemented a MVC model to remedy my issues, but perhaps time and resources allowing I will rewrite it to use the method you describe above. I will mark your answer as accepted. And +1, this is how you expect a table-like component to behave i.e. not having to rebind item clicks every time a new item is added. Thanks, I learned something new today.